# Javascript Button that works for some reason

Tags: javascript

I created a button which will update `SAPReleased__c` only if `Approved__c` is true(`SAPReleased__c` and `Approved__c` are both check boxes).  What I don't understand is.. Why is this working!??

```
        alert(sampling.Approved__c); 
        if(sampling.Approved__c == 'true'){ 
        alert(sampling.Approved__c);
        alert('Inside condition');  
        sampling.SAPReleased__c = true; 

        }else if (sampling.Approved__c == 'false'){ 
        alert('Sample must be approved before it can be booked.'); 
        }
        var result = sforce.connection.update([sampling]); 
        window.location.reload();
```

Now look at my conditions

```
if(sampling.Approved__c == 'true')
else if (sampling.Approved__c == 'false')
```

This doesn't make any sense to me? I am checking to see if they are 'true' or 'false', but isn't this checking to see if its a **String** of true or false while it should be expecting a boolean?

Is this an expected outcome or is this something cooky?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is working because Javascript is doing the type conversion for you. You need to use a '===' to strictly evaluate a boolean like true or false. With a '==' as I understand it, type conversion has to occur before the comparison can be evaluated and type conversion can lead to strange results. In this case though, it's leading to your intended result, which is conversion from boolean to string and the correct evaluation.

Here is a pretty good blog post explaining different equals operators in Javascript:
[Why Use the Triple-Equals Operator in JavaScript?](http://www.impressivewebs.com/why-use-triple-equals-javascipt/)

Comment: It is so I will leave alone, it's just very interesting..